# WIFI blocked once a day

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, internet, connection

I have a really strange behavior, it happens that at certain moment in the morning my wifi connection stops working even if the connection symbol is on. If I try to reconnect to any network I cannot do that. I need to reboot my PC to make my WIFI working again. The strange thing is that this happens once per day and usually around the same hours.
I don't really know what could be!
My laptop is HP ZBook.

Thank you

**EDITED:**
Following @waltinator and @karel suggestions this is what I see from the `sudo journalctl` :

```
Oct 12 13:21:19 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697109679.7711] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 12 13:23:24 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697109804.1025] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 12 13:30:54 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697110254.9692] manager: kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware' changed
Oct 12 13:49:36 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111376.8162] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8021] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8125] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8134] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <warn>  [1697111379.8166] dispatcher: (13) failed: Refusing activation, D-Bus is shutting down.
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8168] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8705] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.8706] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed bound -> done
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.9019] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 12 13:49:39 lx0323838 NetworkManager[1334]: <info>  [1697111379.9076] exiting (success)
```

Comment: What is your DNS set up?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems so much like your ISP is messing with your router that it difficult for me to believe that this has anything to do with Ubuntu, but why would your ISP be messing with your router in the first place? Maybe your ISP has noticed weird performance issues with your router that indicate that your router could be defective, so they are messing with your router to give you a subtle hint that it might be time for you to switch to a different router.

See what else you can find by looking at the network logs.

```
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at my logs. I don't think that is an ISP problem because this seems to happen with different network connections.